# Solving a 2nd order partial differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

The equation at hand is $\Big[\frac{-\hbar}{2m}\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2} + V(x) \Big] \psi(x) = E\psi(x)$. Given are $V(x) = V_0 $ for $x>0$ and $V(x) = 0$ for $x \le 0$ and $\psi(0)=-k/\kappa$. How can I solve this equation and find $\psi(x)$ ?

EDIT:

I proceeded to solve for $\psi(x)$ when $V(x)=0$ by setting $\psi(x)=Ae^{zx}$ and solving for $A,z$. Then I use $\psi(0) = -k/\kappa$ to arrive at $\psi(x)$. Is this correct?

Comment: You have defined the function $V(x)$, but given no boundary conditions. Also, this might originate with a wave equation which is a PDE, but this form of the equation is an ODE.

Comment: There are no boundary conditions, nor do we need them. Now to the point: do you know the solution when $V(x)=\rm const$ for all $x$?

Comment: I agree, that wasn't a boundary condition - I have edited the post accordingly.

Comment: Strangely resembles a Schrödinger equation with a potential wall...

Comment: That is correct, I just found https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/252794 is almost identical to the problem above.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

This is a second order linear ODE with piecewise constant coefficients. You can solve for the two pieces using the standard technique of the characteristic equation. Expect to discuss the sign of $V-E$.

Then join the two partial solutions, enforcing the known "boundary" condition, and possibly other continuity constraints.